# How to get String between multiple delimeter

Tags: java, regex

I have a string:

```
"<field-length-message-total>"
```

Total is an int that varies from 0-99.

I want to output the "total" int value, that is :

```
between "-" & ">".
```

I tried using this Regex generator: http://regexr.com/

My expression was :

```
\-(.*?)\>,
```

instead it grabs the first `-` delimiter.

Comment: Show us exect sample input. Is it something like `"<field-length-message-121>"`?

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar yes exactly

Comment: @newborn , Is it XML ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you :

```
    String s = "<field-length-message-121>";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*?\\-(\\d+)>", "$1"));
```

O/P :

```
121
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lookaround based regex:

```
(?<=-)([^>-]+)(?=>)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gE3zL5/2)

Answer (score 1):

If the 'total' value is always a digit, you could use a single lookbehind:

```
(?<=-)\d+
```

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qS7bG0/1)

---

Input:

```
<field-length-message-77>
```

Matches:

```
77
```